# Which parameters of stars could show they about to undergo a supernova explosion?

Tags: supernova, star-catalogues

I need to seek stars in our galaxy about to undergo a SN from catalogues. I can find stars in our galaxy by setting parallax to a certain value. However, I don't know how to find a parameter which tells me stars are about to undergo SN explosion. What can it be?

Comment: Most of the red giants don't undergo supernova. Mostly hypergiants, supergiants and WN stars undergo supernova.

Comment: You're right. I know that it's short... but might already be the answer?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "about to"? If you just mean stars more massive than say $10M_\odot$ (since their lifetimes are very short) then that might be quite a different problem to identifying stars in the last year before the supernova (which isn;t possible).

Comment: Luminosity type V means they are main sequence stars which are not about to undergo supernova respect to their lives (even their lives are short). So I need stars are at the ending of their evolutionary state. However, Lum type 0-I-II-III-IV means hypergiants, supergiant, brightgiants, giants. If the initial mass is higher that 10M_sun it will turn out the SN II explosion. Here, there is another problem: SN Ia. For SN Ia we need binaries with White Dwarfs near at chandrashekhar limit. So it's not the exact anser what i seek

Comment: Isaac Asimov, "The Currents of Space"